# Using Ajax with celery task

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, celery

I am a bit confused on how to proceed with my program. I have a django view that asks the user to input a first name and lastname, then this go to a celery task which process the data and save it to the database. Now, while the task is processing, I want an animated gif to display so the user will know that something is happening.(I've read somewhere here in SO that animated gif is better) then if the task is done, it will redirect to a page that tells the user the process is complete. I have done my research and found out that I should get the `task_id` and send it to an ajax request.

My problem is how to use ajax. How can I get the task_id from ajax? Or pass the task_id to the ajax request.

---

EDIT:
 ** I know this is INCOMPLETE. VERY INCOMPLETE**

Here is some of my codes. It does not do much because I still have to grasp the concept of using ajax. But what I want is when I submit the form, the spinner gif will appear and at the same time, celery will process my tasks. When celery is done processing the task, it will redirect to a page where it says "Success" or anything.

**views.py:**

```
def addUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       addUser = userform(request.POST)
       if addUser.is_valid():
            task = create_user.apply_async((addUser.cleaned_data,), countdown=20)
       return render_to_response('loading.html', {'task_id': task.task_id})
    else:
       addUser = userform()
    return render(request, 'addUser.html', {'addUser':addUser})
```

**addUser.html**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ addUser }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

**loading.html**

```
<html>
<script>
<head>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var formData = task_id; // task id of my celery task

$.ajax({
    url : "templates/success.html", //from what I know, this URL is where the AJAX will go after processing
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        alert("Success")
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("Failed")
    }
});
</script>

</head>

<body><center>
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/ripple.gif' %}" alt="Hi!" height="150" width="150" />
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task(ignore_result=True)
def create_user(data):
    user = UserInfo(fname=data['fname'], lname=data['lname'])
    user.save()
    return None
```

I am not sure where AJAX will go, if it's in the `form(addUser.html)` or in the `loading.html`

Please do correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

The idea is to launch the long running task, when you execute one it returns an AsyncResult object you have to get the "task_id" and return it to the client.
The client side (javascript) would make a GET request for example to /check_status/ and pass the "task_id" to the server.
The server will ask celery using that task_id and return to the client if the task finished or not.

```
def view_with_task(request):
     #your code
     # send the task to the worker and get the task_id
     async_result = your_task.delay()
     #code
     ctx = {}
     ctx['task_id'] = async_result.task_id
     return render(tpl, ctx)

from celery import AsyncResult
def check_status(request):
    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id')
    if task_id:
        async_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
        return Jsonresponse({'finish': async_result.ready()})
    return JsonResponse({'finish': False})
```

BTW, there is a [project](http://policystat.github.io/jobtastic/) to do this without pain neither too much code.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response! This part is what I want to know `The client side (javascript) would make a GET request for example to /check_status/ and pass the "task_id" to the server.`I saw examples but none of them show me how to do it in the client side.. I checked out the link you provided and I saw that it is only known to work for django 1.3-1.5.. Will this perhaps work with 1.8?

Comment: There is not problem :). That project is aim to use this [link](https://github.com/PolicyStat/jquery-celery/blob/master/src/celery.js#L54) for Javascript. I think they should work with django1.8 havent used with that version yet.
However, you could take a look to that link I have just written and see how the javascript works, for the server-side you have an idea already ( given the "task_id" you can fetch from celery info related to that task =D).
In summary, you could do it by your self or try those libraries together.
Let me know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Oh my. I think this is what I am looking for.. I will give it a try and get back to you if it goes well.

Comment: Found https://github.com/PolicyStat/celeryjs that is somehow related to what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi again. One question though, where would I call my html with the ajax in it? Based on my codes above, where should ajax go? in the addUser.html or the loading.html?

Comment: Pretty late to the conversation but AJAX would go in a js file, and you would simply add an event handler to your HTML that would trigger the AJAX. Never mix Javascript and HTML (React excluded).

Comment: I had to do `from celery.result import AsyncResult`